# Intermittent "Event loop stopped before Future completed."

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have been tearing my hair out at this issue

The code in question is part of an Open Source project here: [aiosmtpd](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd) (my fork of the actual FOSS project, [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd))

The file with the problem is this one: [main.py](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/a0aa0e25bbb013bc03df8b0de98974bfdf67e305/aiosmtpd/main.py)

The piece of code in which the problem happens is on [line 139 of main.py](https://github.com/pepoluan/aiosmtpd/blob/a0aa0e25bbb013bc03df8b0de98974bfdf67e305/aiosmtpd/main.py#L139)

Here's a snippet:

```py
...
from aiosmtpd.smtp import DATA_SIZE_DEFAULT, SMTP, __version__
...

...

    # args is the result of ArgumentParser.parse_args

    factory = partial(
        SMTP, args.handler,
        data_size_limit=args.size, enable_SMTPUTF8=args.smtputf8)

    ...

    server = loop.run_until_complete(
        loop.create_server(factory, host=args.host, port=args.port))

    ...
```

**Sometimes** -- that is, *not always* -- the code failed at that point with `RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.`

My questions:

1. What could be the cause of this **intermittent** failure?

   It failed like 10% of the time during testing (using tox + nosetest2), but 90% of the time just went swimmingly well.
2. How should I instrument and/or check and/or assert to prevent this from happening?
3. What's the best strategy for "recovering" the error and redoing the action?

---

I will emphasize for the n-th time that **the error happens INTERMITTENTLY**. And infrequently, but often enough so I feel compelled to trace the root cause. And after an error, if I rerun the code again -- immediately or after a delay -- the same error nearly always did NOT happen.

Comment: Look for calls to `loop.stop()` somewhere in the code base. You probably want to remove those, as they are fundamentally incompatible with `run_until_complete`, as well as with the more modern `asyncio.run`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Nope, no `loop.stop()` within those two problematic lines. `factory` was a simple `partial` wrap around another class, and within that class there is no `loop.stop()` anywhere. Remember that I repeatedly emphasized **"intermittent"**; existence of `loop.stop()` within the code will result in "always" instead of "intermittent".

Comment: I understand that `loop.stop()` is not present in those lines, but there is a high probability that it's present somewhere else in the code base, perhaps even in a library which stops the loop in case of an event it can't handle. Barring a bug in asyncio, the only way for the message to occur is by someone calling `loop.stop()`, so that's what I'd look for first. If that doesn't show anything, the next step would be to annotate asyncio to find out how the message is reached _without_ a prior call to `loop.stop()` - but it's much more likely you'll find `loop.stop()` in the previous step.

Comment: @user4815162342 As I commented earlier (which I might not have made clear enough, my bad) I _have_ traced out from line 139. _Nowhere_ within the call stack invoked from line 139 do I find any instance of `loop.stop()`. In addition -- and I _really_ emphasized this -- the error only happened **intermittently**. Meaning: Sometimes (actually quite infrequently) the error happened. Most of the times, the code runs without any problem. The existence of `loop.stop()` anywhere in the call stack will cause constant error instead of intermittent.

Comment: You can check the `_stopping` attribute on the event loop at the point when the exception is raised, I'd expect it to be true, otherwise `run_forever()` invoked by `run_until_complete()` wouldn't halt. In asyncio `_stopping` is set to true only from `stop()`, but maybe someone else is setting it. And you don't need to explain what intermittent means because it is not in contradiction with what I wrote: the call to `loop.stop()` could be under a specific *condition* which does not trip every time.

Comment: @user4815162342 That's why this problem is confusing for me. I do a whole-project search for `.stop()` and found it only on 3 places: One in a test case not related to this, one in a module totally not accessed by `main.py` nor by `test_main.py` (the test case where the error happened), and one in `main.py` _far after_ line 139. So if there's any `loop.stop()` call, it's gotta happen within `asyncio` itself. That begets the question: On what circumstances `asyncio` will `stop()` a loop without being asked?

Comment: Did your whole-project search include the dependencies? Also, have you checked whether `_stopping` is true when the error occurs? If so, then _someone_ has either set it directly or by calling `stop()`, so I'd search for both `stop` and `_stopping` in the project and its dependencies. If not, then there must be another path for `loop_forever` to exit, which can also be investigated.

Comment: @user4815162342 The whole package has one dependency, `atpublic` and that module does not touch asyncio in any way. When exception happens `loop._stopping` returns `False`. What then?

Comment: When the exception is raised or caught it's already too late because `run_forever` has already completed by then, and `_stopping` gets reset to False [before that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13ff396c019d548ba181cf22c6f39309a300723c/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L600). You can check whether `_stopping` is true inside `run_forever` by instrumenting or stepping through asyncio itself. If so, check (perhaps by temporarily changing `_stopping` to a property) at which point it gets set. If not, you can add debugging prints to check how `run_forever` exited without `_stopping` being true.

Comment: @user4815162342  "by instrumenting or stepping through asyncio" so, you're suggesting that I debug `asyncio` itself? Doesn't sound great, I'm not being paid for that. Oh well, let's hear from others who have a better idea.

Comment: More "investigate what's going on" than debug, but yes, based on the data you gave that's what I'd try next, especially given that that part of asyncio is quite easy to follow.

Comment: @user4815162342 Okay first an apology: After tracing I finally found `loop.stop`. It was passed to `call_later` in `test_main.py`. I missed that because I searched for `.stop(`. Apparently `call_later` was set with too small a delay causing it to trigger before `run_until_complete`. I enlarged the delay by several hundred percent and now I no longer see the same error.

Comment: @user4815162342 If you can convert your comment into an Answer, I'll gladly choose your answer as the correct answer and award you the bounty.

Comment: No problem, glad the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Barring a bug in asyncio, the issue is likely caused by a call to `loop.stop()` hidden somewhere in the code base. You probably want to remove or disable those, as they are fundamentally incompatible with `run_until_complete`, as well as with the more modern `asyncio.run`.