# Python's asyncio's event loop stops after TCP client disconnection

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am running a TCP client that recieves packets from various devices. I am using asyncio's stream library for it.
The issue is that when I stop the TCP server that the client is connected to, the event loop stops and the programs stops without any error. This happens despite not sending the STOP signal. This is the code:

```py
async def read_messages(connected_clients: dict, mqtt_client: MQTTClient):
    while True:
        if not connected_clients:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            continue

        async for mac, client_dict in get_connected_clients(connected_clients):
            reader: asyncio.StreamReader = client_dict.get("reader")
            ip: str = client_dict.get("ip")
            writer: asyncio.StreamWriter = client_dict.get("writer")
            try:
                data: bytes = await reader.read(1024)
            except ConnectionResetError or ConnectionAbortedError or ConnectionRefusedError or ConnectionError:
                logging.warning(f"Connection Error for {mac} running on {ip}")
                mqtt_client.message_publish(
                    MQTT_ERROR_TOPIC, 1, f"Connection Error for {mac} running on {ip}"
                )
                del connected_clients[mac]
                break
```

After I disconnect the client from the server, the exception "Connection Error" hits and the async for loop breaks but theorietically the main while loop should still be running but its not. The program stops without any error.

Comment: How do you run the event loop? What does the rest of your program look like? Maybe you have `loop.stop()` somewhere in the program, and it hits along with the exception.

Comment: @user4815162342 I don't have loop.stop() anywhere. Here is the redacted version of the code:https://gist.github.com/mntolia/9493e93297dbad1a2f012047202efb9a

Comment: Then maybe some dependency does it, because otherwise the program couldn't exit `run_forever`. Take a look at my comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64282224/1600898) about a related issue for ideas how to debug this one.

Comment: Also, in the code from the gist, `read_messages` wouldn't even execute because you await `periodic_ping` first, which never halts. That's probably just an unintended effect of the redaction, but maybe it matters.

Comment: @user4815162342 Actually read_messages() does execute. 

You maybe right. It might be linked to gmqtt. I ll check that out. Thanks

Comment: agreed any other dependency calls such as `await send_udp_message` could be terminating your main task during execution meaning the event loop has 0 task remaining (and issues the python kill signal?). maybe check if these other dependency calls are bound in a loop

Comment: @LoveenDyall Asyncio has no concept of a "main task". Even if all tasks complete, there could still be a callback scheduled off a timeout or signal handler which could perform useful work, including adding more tasks. The event loop run with `run_forever()`, as the OP runs it, won't "exit when number of tasks reaches 0", it will just keep going. (`run_until_complete` and `asyncio.run` call `run_forever` and explicitly terminate the event loop when the task they've been given completes.) The OP's issue is almost certainly caused by a rogue `loop.stop()` somewhere in the code.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run clearly states `.run` will close the threadpool. maybe you are referring to older asyncio versions. Also, the "main task" in my comment is synonymous with "main thread" where other threads containing asyncio Tasks can be initialised, meaning the "main task" still has remaining execution cycles in respective event loops belonging to respective threads.

Comment: So I used the debugger and figured it was the "continue" in the async for loop causing the event loop to stop. When I comment out that line I don't have any issue. I am not sure how continue in async for works. I think I ll have to check that out.